# Runtime compiling c++ into memory on msvc

Tags: c++

I'm working on an experiment that makes use of something similar to a perfect hash function. I could make it go much faster if I could compile these relatively simple generated functions during runtime. Heres an example of what one of these functions would look like:

```
void something(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int &g, int &h, int &i, int &j) {
    g = a + b / d * (f + 2) - c;
    h = g * 2 + a / b;
    i = f / g + a;
    j = (f + 1) * 3 + g / a / b * c;
}
```

Well.. they would actually be much longer but the principle is the same, some output = some combination of inputs/outputs, all defined in the function, no need to access any external code.

My platform is windows with VS 2013, are there any std tools for this perhaps? or some GPL library you can recommend?

Comment: *if I could compile these relatively simple generated functions during runtime* I am not sure I understand. How would it improve speed to compile at runtime?

Comment: Are you generating these at runtime and interpreting them? Why do you need to generate functions at runtime?

Comment: Currently I have a class "dynafunc" that holds 2 pointers to other dynafunc instances. Each dynafunc has a pair of either constant or variable inputs and performs one mathematical operation with the two. By chaining these together I can dynamically define a chain like a = b + 3 - c or whatever. Solving those dynamic "functions" is relatively slow however, the solver has to walk through each step and check the type of the operation, make calls to get the inputs etc, just a lot of overhead compared to compiled code.

Comment: @user81993 is this like an abstract syntax tree and an AST-walking interpreter? If so, you can transform it into a JIT compiler using something like [DynASM](http://luajit.org/dynasm.html) or [LLVM](http://llvm.org).

Comment: @user81993 Adding your detailed explanation to the question would probably improve the chances for a good answer.